# Unable to activate SSL on XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, ssl, woocommerce, xampp, localhost

I'm having issues with creating a certificate to use with XAMPP. I've been looking everywhere for a solution but I can't seem to find one that works for me.

So I'm following this guide (reading to the comments not a lot of people are happy with it tho but I don't find anything else): https://gist.github.com/nguyenanhtu/33aa7ffb6c36fdc110ea8624eeb51e69

And in the first step they ask you to run the makecert.bat that's located in the C:\xampp\apache directory.

When I run it I get this error:

```
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
......................+++
........+++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:testen

2684:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:.\crypto\ui\ui_lib.c:831:You must type in 4 to 511 characters
2684:error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:116:
2684:error:0907E06F:PEM routines:DO_PK8PKEY:read key:.\crypto\pem\pem_pk8.c:130:
unable to load Private Key
1204:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:708:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
server.csr: No such file or directory
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\server.csr
Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.

-----
Das Zertifikat wurde erstellt.
The certificate was provided.
```

As it says, there is no server.csr located in that directory, it's located under \xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr

If I go to chrome and go to https://localhost/project I get the warning that the connection is not secure, if I click on advanced and move on I can continue on https eventhough the browser doesn't show the green safe thingy.

Problem is I'm working on with a woocommerce shop and the API, the API needs a secure connection.

Anyone that can help me solve this issue please? Thank you! I'm eager to learn. :)

Comment: Green Bar is shown only if you get SSL certificate from any trusted seller/provider. Self-generated certificates can't be green.

Comment: Also - All of your resources need to be gotten through https if you want the green tick - If by example, you get the bootstrap cdn though http, then it won't be green

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks for the info. I managed to get the API working.